# Providing placeholder info while ckeditor loads?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

On my fast dev PC it takes a few seconds for the CKEditor to initialize once it is called. On many PCs, this will take longer.

I want to display some info to the user while the CKEditor is loading. "Please wait while the editor loads..." or something like that.

I'm sure there must be some way of doing this, but I can't find anything on how to do it. For instance, they might be a "ckeditorloaded" event I could listen for.

How do I display an element to the user while the CKEditor is loading, that disappears once it has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery you can easily add an element that is visible while it's loading, and remove it on CKEDITOR's instanceReady event.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e){ /* hide the loading element here */ });
```

Kind regard,
ElChe